# Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 ti doesn't work in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have the no longer new Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 ti graphic card. I tried installing the Nvidia drivers directly from the Nvidia site (latest available NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.21.run) and ubuntu won't boot. I always end in this support dialog box "reduce resolution" but none of the options work and I get an unusable system. I had the exact same problem with a Nvidia Quadro K2200 card.

Is there a way to install either of these two cards using some PPT or whatever works because the official nvidia drivers as of today won't do the job.

Comment: Did it ultimately work?

Comment: Any update on the issue?

Answer (score 4):

If you did a kernel upgrade then @Zilvador answer may be good for you.

If not the issue is the driver from Nvidia's site as there linux support is rubbish (but getting better thanks to steam).

Boot the system and press ctrl+alt+f1 to get a terminal, log in and remove the driver like this

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then use the one from the Ubuntu repos that is tested

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common-updates
```

This one should work great with your card.

Answer (score 4):

Install the drivers this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you by any chance have a kernel upgrade since you installed the driver? I have a similar graphic card and I have the same issues when upgrading the kernel, meaning that I need to install the driver again every time.

You probably know the installation procedure, but I will write it here below. Unfortunately NVIDIA requires that the graphic user interface is not running while installing it, so it will be necessary to log out of the computer first. Steps described below:

1. Log out of your Ubuntu session (or boot the computer)
2. When at the login screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F1. It will switch to a command line interface.
3. Write your Ubuntu user name followed by password to log in
4. Write `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`
5. Now you can install the driver. Write `cd /path/to/installer` followed by `sudo chmod +x NVIDIA*`
6. Install the driver by typing `sudo sh NVIDIA*`. It will take you to an installation wizard, where you have to click your way through.
7. When you're done, go back to the login screen by pressing `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start`

As said, unfortunately this has to be done after every kernel upgrade as it is now. That is how far Linux support from NVIDIA goes right now.

Comment: I know this drill and have done it a million times before, it hasn't worked in this instance though.